# Type Error: undefined is not a function(evaluating 'this.state.tableData.map')

Tags: react-native, typeerror

I have created table fetching array from API but it is giving me an error

> That is Type Error: **undefined is not a function(evaluating
>    'this.state.tableData.map')**
>
> I have to display fetched data in a table in react-native in my android
>   application*

```
  <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>

      <Row data={this.state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
      <TableWrapper style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Col style={styles.col} textStyle={styles.text}
          data={this.state.tableData.map(function (object) {
            return (
                   <Text key={object.id}>   {object.deviceType}</Text>
                  );
        })}/>

        <Col style={styles.col} textStyle={styles.text} 
         data= {this.state.tableData.map(function (object) {
           return (
               <Text key={object.id}>   {object.InTime}</Text>    
             );
        })} />

        <Col style={styles.col} textStyle={styles.text}
           data={this.state.tableData.map(function (object) {
              return (
                <Text key={object.id}>   {object.OutTime}</Text>
                );
        })}/>
      </TableWrapper>

    </Table>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThFsj.png

Comment: please upload some more details like response of api , full code of your component .

Comment: let user=await AsyncStorage.getItem('AsyncRfid');
        fetch('https://stsapp.000webhostapp.com/api/app/timing.php', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({rfid:user})})
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((res) => {this.setState({
      tableData:res
                })
       })
            .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert(error.message);
            });}

Comment: https://stsapp.000webhostapp.com/api/app/timing.php this the api link

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding code in comments , also add what response you are getting from api.

Comment: stack overflow not letting me add that much code in question

Comment: What does this.state.tableData contain? I think it may not be an array, hence the error.

Comment: stsapp.000webhostapp.com/api/app/timing.php this is the link which can show u the data which is fetched

Comment: You should initialise your state variable in the constructor of your component (initialise state.tableData as an array). The problem could be that tableData is not defined when the component starts rendering, but only gets defined when the api call returns a value, which is done asynchronously so it throws the error on initial render. Check these docs for an example of what you should do - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize your state variable `tableData` to an empty `array` inside your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableData : []
     };
  }
```

Also check your `tableData` value from response should not be `undefined` if the value is `undefined` you need to handle it.

Another thing is that you can refer the simple table implementation [here](https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component)if `tableData` is a two-dimensional array